# Cloning table row and adding it to end of table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to clone and append a table row when the user selects my add rows button. I have an empty hidden row that is used to clone. I can't seem to get it to work how I need it too.

I output my form with PHP and looks something like this:

```
$budgetRowCount = 0;

echo"<table id='selected_budget_table'>
        <tr>
        <th>Roofs</th>
        <th>Roof Area</th>
        <th>Recommendations</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>";

echo   "<tr id='new_budget_row0' style='display: none;'>
        <td><input id='budget-roofs' name='budget-roofs[]' /></td>
        <td><input id='budget-area' name='budget-area[]' /></td>
        <td><input id='budget-recommendation' name='budget-recommendations[]' /></td>
        <td><input id='budget-amount' name='budget-amount[]'/> </td>
    </tr>";


while ($budgetInfoRow = mysqli_fetch_array($budgetResult)) {

if($budgetRowCount == 0){
    echo "<tr id='selected_budget_row". $budgetRowCount ."'>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='budget-roofs' name='budget-roofs[]' value='".$budgetInfoRow['budget_roofs']."'</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='budget-roof-area' name='budget-roof-area[]' value='".$budgetInfoRow['budget_roof_area']."'</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='budget-recommendation' name='budget-recommendation[]' value='".$budgetInfoRow['budget_recommendation']."'</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='budget-amount' name='budget-amount[]' value='".$budgetInfoRow['budget_amount']."'</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $budgetRowCount++;
}
else{
    echo "<tr id='selected_budget_row". $budgetRowCount ."'>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='budget-roofs' name='budget-roofs[]' value='".$budgetInfoRow['budget_roofs']."'</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='budget-roof-area' name='budget-roof-area[]' value='".$budgetInfoRow['budget_roof_area']."'</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='budget-recommendation' name='budget-recommendation[]' value='".$budgetInfoRow['budget_recommendation']."'</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='budget-amount' name='budget-amount[]' value='".$budgetInfoRow['budget_amount']."'</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='#' class='removeRow' data-remove-row='budget_row". $budgetRowCount . "'>Remove</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $budgetRowCount++;
}
}

echo "</table>";

echo"<input type='button' value='+' id='addNewBudgetRow'     class='addNewBudgetRow'/>";
```

And this is how I am attempting to clone my row and add it to my table:

```
$(function() {

var $removeIDVal = 0;

$(document.body).on('click', '.addNewBudgetRow', function () {
    var $emptyBudgetTableRow = $("#new_budget_row0").clone();
    $removeIDVal++
    var $emptyBudgetTableRowClone = $emptyBudgetTableRow.clone();
    var $newRowID = 'added_budget_row' + $removeIDVal;
    $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.attr('id', $newRowID)
    $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.children('td').last().after('<td><a href="#" class="removeRow" data-remove-row="' + $newRowID + '">Remove</a></td>');
    $(this).closest("fieldset").find("tbody").append($emptyBudgetTableRowClone);
    $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.show();
   });
});
```

I had an alert to check if the button was actually firing and my alert showed up no problem, however I can't seem to get it to clone and append properly and I have done this several times elsewhere with no issues. Where am I going wrong here?

How can I fix this so that my row gets cloned properly and added to the end of my table?

Comment: No errors in the console? Can you setup a jsFiddle?

Comment: @JayBlanchard No errors at all, yeah I will set one up now.

Comment: Can you add the actual HTML that's generated to the question, instead of the PHP. Note that you're also cloning the row twice. The first clone is redundant, although this won't cause any issues.

Comment: ids are singular and you have a lot of repeated ids. Why are you calling clone of a clone?

Comment: `$emptyBudgetTableRowClone.children('td').last().after(...)` is the same thing as `$emptyBudgetTableRowClone.append(...)`

Comment: @epascarello Actually it's not, the first line I am adding in another `<td>`, and the second line I am appending my cloned row to the table.

Comment: You misread it.... Has nothing to do with appending the row to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not selecting your table, since you have no `<fieldset>` or `<tbody>`. Select it by id.

Alos you were cloning new row twice and you have multiple same ids.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.addNewBudgetRow', function () {
    var $emptyBudgetTableRowClone = $("#new_budget_row0").clone();
    $removeIDVal++
    var $newRowID = 'added_budget_row' + $removeIDVal;
    $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.attr('id', $newRowID)
    $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.children('td').last().after('<td><a href="#" class="removeRow" data-remove-row="' + $newRowID + '">Remove</a></td>');
    $('#selected_budget_table').append($emptyBudgetTableRowClone);
    $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.show();
   });
});
```

```js
$(function() {

var $removeIDVal = 0;

$(document.body).on('click', '.addNewBudgetRow', function () {
    var $emptyBudgetTableRowClone = $("#new_budget_row0").clone();
    $removeIDVal++
    var $newRowID = 'added_budget_row' + $removeIDVal;
    $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.attr('id', $newRowID)
    $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.children('td').last().after('<td><a href="#" class="removeRow" data-remove-row="' + $newRowID + '">Remove</a></td>');

    // Select you table by id
    $('#selected_budget_table').append($emptyBudgetTableRowClone);
    $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.show();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='selected_budget_table'>
    <tr>
        <th>Roofs</th>
        <th>Roof Area</th>
        <th>Recommendations</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
   </tr>
   <tr id='new_budget_row0' style='display: none;'>
        <td><input id='budget-roofs' name='budget-roofs[]' /></td>
        <td><input id='budget-area' name='budget-area[]' /></td>
        <td><input id='budget-recommendation' name='budget-recommendations[]' /></td>
        <td><input id='budget-amount' name='budget-amount[]'/> </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<input type='button' value='+' id='addNewBudgetRow' class='addNewBudgetRow'/>
```

Comment: Ah damn, yep that's exactly it, thanks for the help! Yeah I am working on the ID issue now.

Comment: Why do you need ids on all the elements?

Answer (score 0):

I've put it up on jsFiddle and found + fixed some issues:

http://jsfiddle.net/lumpie/nprsdb2m/

```
$(function() {
    var $removeIDVal = 0;
    $(document.body).on('click', '.addNewBudgetRow', function () {
        var $emptyBudgetTableRow = $("#new_budget_row0");
        $removeIDVal++
        var $emptyBudgetTableRowClone = $emptyBudgetTableRow.clone();
        var $newRowID = 'added_budget_row' + $removeIDVal;
        $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.attr('id', $newRowID)
        $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.append('<td><a href="#" class="removeRow" data-remove-row="' + $newRowID + '">Remove</a></td>');

        $("#selected_budget_table").append($emptyBudgetTableRowClone);

        // Logic to remove a row:
        $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.find(".removeRow").click(function() { 
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        });
        $emptyBudgetTableRowClone.show();
    });
});
```

Ah, just a minute too late, Rene Korss was slightly ahead of me.

But hey: I've included a little extra: logic to make the Remove button work :)

Comment: I appreciate the effort and such but your fiddle doesn't seem to work. Also the remove button already works;)

Comment: I've just tested it again in Chrome and IE 11 and it works fine on my machine... What's not working on yours?